# Spring MVC Custom View

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am refactoring a legacy application to use Spring MVC.  All of my controllers (legacy) return an object of type Model and my legacy dispatcher write the output of model.getContent(), the method getContent does internal processing and returns a json string.  I have hundreds of controllers and do not want to rewrite them.  Is it possible to write a custom view handler and include it in the spring servlet config?

Sample Controller:

```
public UserList extends BasicAction {
  @Autowired
  UserService userService;
  @Autowired
  UserCommand userCommand;

  @Override
    public Model getModel(Request req, Response resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Model model = new Model();


        List<User> users;
        try {
            users = userService.getUsers((UserCriteria)userCommand.getResult());
            model.addCollection(users);
            model.setWrapper(new UserWrapper());


        } catch (ValidationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (WebCommandException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return model;
    }
}
```

I'm planning to annotate as @Controller.  Specify the @RequestMapping or in the xml config, remove the base class BasicAction (legacy mvc).  I've recently introduced spring to this project and refactored to use Dependency Injection and Request Scoped command objects (request wrappers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward is to implement `View` interface on your `Model` class. Then your legacy controllers can return this class directly (as they are now) and it will get rendered by `DispatcherServlet` via calling its `render` method.

Another possibility is to implement your own `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, where the handler can actually render the response and mark the response as handled (`mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);`) so that `DispatcherServlet` will not try to render any view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is create a custom ViewResolver that outputs your JSON response.  This would be configured in Spring MVC to set the ViewResolver list, placing yours up top to have more precedence.  The way it is supposed to work (from my recollection) is that Spring MVC will start at the top of the list, and try each ViewResolver until it finds one that returns the one that handles the return type.  You will have to google how to make custom ViewResolvers, as I have only used them, never created one, but I know it's an interface so it should be do-able.  I believe this would be the only way to do this that would not require any code changes in your controllers.

The more "preferred" method to do JSON, however, is to have Jackson in your classpath and simply return the object you want to serialize to JSON.  Spring will auto-magically convert that to JSON, I believe using a ViewResolver they provide.  But, I can surely relate to not wanting to refactor lots of working code.